# How can I transfer the selected table from a list of database tables inside <select></select> form to another <select></select> form

Tags: javascript

[image: This the scenario]

This is my current code:

```
<div class="column" id="tbDiv">
    <p><b>TABLES</b></p>
    <select name="List of Tables" size="25" multiple id='table1' name='table1' title='List of Tables' class='inputbox'>
        <option>Tables will be listed here...</option></select>
</div> 
</td>

<td>
    <div class="column">                  
        <button onclick="myFunction1()" style="float:right; margin-right:0px;" id="submit1"><<</button>
        <button onclick="myFunction2()" style="float:right; margin-right:0px;" id="submit">>></button>  
     </div>
</td> 
<td>             
    <div class="column">
        <p><b>TABLE(S) TO SYNC</b></p>
        <select name="List of Tables" size="25" multiple name='table1' title='List of selected tables' name="List of Tables" size="20" class='inputbox'>
             <option>. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

How can I transfer a selected table from the left dropdownlist to the right, or vice versa?

Comment: Ctrl-A Ctrl-C move mouse Ctrl-V ??

Comment: Your screen shot looks like some kind of UI.  Most UIs have Ctrl-A for "select all", Ctrl-C for "copy", and Ctrl-V for "paste".  I was making a biiiig guess that that UI would let you copy all the table names that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tikoflano/bk329wwv/) with what I think you are looking for. Using jQuery is very simple to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#tables option:selected").each(function(){
           $(this).clone().appendTo("#tables_to_sync");
           $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    $("#remove").click(function(){
        $("#tables_to_sync option:selected").each(function(){
           $(this).clone().appendTo("#tables");
           $(this).remove();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Why use the `.clone()` and `.remove()`? You can just append those elements to another `<select>` and it'll move them. Then it'll keep them highlighted but that's easy to undo after... See this [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk329wwv/1/).

Comment: That's true. I'm still learning jQuery. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Ah well that's alright. As a matter of fact you can shorten it even more... See this edit (replaced `$(document).ready()` and `.each()`): http://jsfiddle.net/bk329wwv/2/